# SQL - Filter on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, hiveql

I am trying to get of the count of two columns with a where clause on each column individually in sql.

Lets say my data looks like

```
person feature1   feature2
a       1           1
a       0           1
a       1           1
a       1           1
a       0           0
a       1           1
b       0           1
c       1           0
```

Now, I want to group the data by person and the grouped data should look like

```
  person feature1   feature2
    a       2           1
    b       0           1
    c       1           0
```

I wanted to count the no of zeros of each column per person. How can I do this through sql.

Comment: Feature 1 for row b should be 1 i guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to do this. Conditions in `sum` return 1 or 0 depending on true or false.

```
select person,sum(feature1=0),sum(feature2=0)
from tbl
group by person
```

In Hive, you should cast the boolean returned to `int`before summing up.

```
select person,sum(cast(feature1=0 as int)),sum(cast(feature2=0 as int))
from tbl
group by person
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use case statement to count non zero features for each person

select person,
    count(case when feature1>0 then 1 else null end) F1,
    count(case when feature1>0 then 1 else null end) F2
    from Table1
    group by person ;

Comment: `else null` is redundant